# exchange web services x509 Certivicate

Tags: x509, exchangewebservices, x509certificate2, x509securitytokenmanager

I am trying to connect to Exchange Web Services to send an email on behalf of a user through my own Web Service (ASP/WCF). My code works fine when running on a desktop PC able to connect to the exchange server but when operating over the internet the exchange server can not be accessed, thus I am trying to connect through my web server instead.

I am looking for ways to login as another user without using Exchange Web Services impersonation (as I have been told to not use that unless there is absolutely no other way) and without the user providing their password.

I have the following code:

```
Dim service As New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
Dim emailAddress As String = "example@example.com"
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf CertificateValidationCallBack


Dim cert As New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate)
service.Credentials = New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials(New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate())
service.UseDefaultCredentials = False
```

But this does not work because of an `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate' to type 'System.Net.ICredentials'.` exception.

Can anyone direct me on how I might use an X509 certificate to authenticate against Exchange Web Services rather than using network credentials or username/password

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this without error

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```